# Add methods to a model using entity framework

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, orm

With entity framework, is it possible to add methods to an object class ?
For example, i have a CLIENT mapping and i would like to create a "getAgeFromBirhDate" method.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Yes. It's possible. Entity Framework generates [Partial Classes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wa80x488.aspx).

That means you can create another file that contains another portion of the Partial Class definition (with your additional methods) and everything will work just fine.

Comment: using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace FOO.Models
{
    public partial class FOO_USERS
    {
        public void bar()
        { 
            //the code of the method here
        }
    }
}

Comment: How can I make database queries inside methods of an entity definition?

Answer (score 6):

An example for the first answer:

if you have an entity named `Flower` you can use this `partial` class for adding method to it:

```
namespace Garden //same as namespace of your entity object
{
    public partial class Flower  
    {
        public static Flower Get(int id)
        { 
            //
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
public static class ModelExtended
{
    public static void SaveModelToXML(this Model1Container model, string xmlfilePath)
    {
        ///some code
    }
}
```

Comment: This will create a extension method which is fine most the time. However, If you want to add a property (to target it in property-expressions), partial classes will be the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have your partial class with an Entity Framework attribute price from the database:

```
    namespace Garden //same as namespace of your entity object
    {
        public partial class Flower  
        {
            public int price;
            public string name;
            // Any other code ...
        }
    }
```

if you don't want to use another partial class, you can define your own custom class containing the original entity stored as an attribute. You can add then any extra custom attribute and method

```
namespace Garden //same as namespace of your entity object
{
    public class CustomFlower  
    {
        public Flower originalFlowerEntityFramework;

        // An extra custom attribute
        public int standardPrice;


        public CustomFlower(Flower paramOriginalFlowerEntityFramework)
        { 
            this.originalFlowerEntityFramework = paramOriginalFlowerEntityFramework
        }


        // An extra custom method
        public int priceCustomFlowerMethod()
        {
            if (this.originalFlowerEntityFramework.name == "Rose" ) 
                return this.originalFlowerEntityFramework.price * 3 ;
            else 
                return this.price ;
        }

    }
}
```

Then wherever you want to use it, you create your custom class object and store in it the one from the Entity Framework :

```
//Your Entity Framework class
Flower aFlower = new Flower();
aFlower.price = 10;
aFlower.name = "Rose";

// or any other code ...

// Your custom class
CustomFlower cFlower =  new CustomFlower(aFlower);
cFlower.standardPrice = 20;

MessageBox.Show( "Original Price : " + cFlower.originalFlowerEntityFramework.price );
// Will display 10
MessageBox.Show( "Standard  price : " + cFlower.standardPrice );
// Will display 20
MessageBox.Show( "Custom Price : " + cFlower.priceCustomFlowerMethod() );
// Will display 30
```